# consultar la base de datos con python con rango de fechas desde el formulario html

Tags: javascript, html, python

Tengo este código html para ingresar los rangos de fechas de inicio y finalización

```
<input id="fechaInicio" type="text" 
<input id="fechaFinal" type="text" 
<a onclick = "listadoConsulta()" href="#" class="btn"
```

el javascrip es este:

```
async function listadoConsulta() {
document.getElementById('fechaInicio').value = date1
document.getElementById('fechaFinal').value = date2

var url = URLSERVIDOR + 'listado/consulta'
var respuesta = await fetch(url, {
"method": 'GET',
"headers":{
    "Content-Type": 'application/json'
}
}) 
listado = await respuesta.json();
var html = ''
for (registro of listado) {

var row = `<tr>
<td>${registro.folio}</td>
<td>${registro.lote}</td>
<td>${registro.tabla}</td>
<td>${registro.cajas}</td>
<td>${registro.peso_neto}</td>
</tr>`
    html = html + row;
 }
document.querySelector('#tablaFechas> tbody').outerHTML 
 = html
```

y la consulta de la base de datos en python:

```
 @app.route('/api/listado/consulta')
 @cross_origin()
 def listadoConsulta():
 ejecutarListado = mysql.connection.cursor()
 #date1 = "20220920"
 #date2 = "20220921"
 ejecutarListado.execute('SELECT id, folio, lote, 
 tabla, cajas, peso_neto FROM 
 `registrocorte` WHERE `fecha` BETWEEN ' + date1 +  " 
 AND " + date2 + ';')
 datos = ejecutarListado.fetchall()
 resultadoLista = []
 for fila in datos:
 contenido = {'id': fila[0],
             'folio': fila[1],
             'lote': fila[2],
             'tabla': fila[3],
             'cajas': fila[4],
             'peso_neto': fila[5]
             }
 resultadoLista.append(contenido)
 return jsonify(resultadoLista)
```

AHORA A VER SI PUEDO FORMULAR BIEN LA PREGUNTA.
TODO FUNCIONA BIEN… PERO COMO PUEDO AGREGAR LOS DATOS DESDE EL HTML, POR QUE ASÍ COMO ESTA EL CODIGO LA FECHA ESTA INGRESADO MANUAL Y LO QUE OCUPO COMUNICAR ES EL CODIGO JAVASCRIPT CON LA CONSULTA EN PYTHON. PARA QUE AL INGRESAR LAS FECHAS DE INICIO Y FIN EN EL HTML ME DEVUELVA LOS DATOS DE LA BD FILTRADOS POR LA FECHA.

Comment: Por favor, pulsa en [edit] y reemplaza las mayúsculas: ¡NO ES NECESARIO GRITAR!

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza request, ejemplo

```
fecha_inicio = request.form.get('fechaInicio')
```

esto si esta dentro de un formulario, si es un parametro tendrias que usar lo siguiente:

```
mi_parametro = request.args.get("mi_parametro")
```

PD: no te olvides de importar request desde flask